# Why object is not updating as NULL

Tags: c#, object

When I am updating my `obj` as `null` its output is 30 but no exception but when I am updating `obj.Age = 25` output is 25.

I am not getting the idea what is happening behind the scene.
Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
public class A
{
    public int age;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Test(A obj)
    {
        //obj = null;
        //obj.age = 25;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            A obj = new A();
            obj.age = 30;
            Test(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.age);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the method signature -

```
public static void Test(A obj)
```

The parameter is not passed as `ref`. When the reference types are passed as parameter, without specifying as `ref`. You can change the properties values within the object, but you cannot assign the object to point it to another memory location.

In simple words you cannot do -
`obj = null` OR `obj = new A()` OR `obj = instanceOfAnotherObject`

To be able to even change the object, you need to change the method signature and pass obj by ref -

```
public static void Test(ref A obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `obj = null;` then you do not set the object to null but the reference to that object to `null`. As in your method `Test` the parameter is a new reference to the passed object, it does not affect the `obj` reference in `Main` and so setting `obj` to `null` in `Test` has only an effect in that method.
To do / see what you want you may want to change the parameter of `Test` to a [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) parameter like so

```
public static void Test(ref A obj)
```

and then call `Test` like so

```
...
A obj = new A();
obj.age = 30;
Test(ref obj);
...
```

as now you actually modify the `obj` reference of the `Main` method.

---

When you do `obj.age = 25;` in `Test` (of course without setting `obj` to `null` in front of it) then you modify the same object as `obj` in `Main` points to and so when writing the `age` to the console you will see 25.
That is possible because it was passed by reference - if you replace `A` with e.g. `int` and pass that around then changing its value in `Test` will not be reflected in the output of `Main` as integers are passed by value. You may find reading this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx) and the subsequent pages to it helpful